# $http.get unable to fetch data from SpringBoot controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, dynamic-tables

I am creating an application which will run queries on my store's database, based on what the user enters on the webpage. I have successfully created the backend method. And it successfully returns the response. But I am unable to retrieve the data and display it on my webpage in the form of a dynamic table. I am a bit new to AngularJS, so please bear with me, but any help is appreciated.

**StoreController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/runQuery", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Map<String, Object>> runQuery(@RequestParam(value="query", defaultValue="* FROM items") String statement, Model model)  {
    List<Map<String, Object>> answer = storeService.executeUserQuery(statement);
    model.addAttribute("resultList", answer);
    return answer;
}
```

I tried to model my controller in such a way that it can dynamically take the data received from the Java controller and assign it to the $scope variable.

**app.module.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []);
})();
```

**store.controller.js**

```
angular
.module('app').controller('StoreController', ['$scope','StoreService','StoreController','$q', function ($scope,StoreService, StoreController, $q) {

    $scope.runQuery = function () {

               StoreService.runQuery($scope.statement)
              .then (function (data){
                  $scope.rows = response.data;
                  $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
              },
              function error(response){
                  if (response.status == 404){
                  $scope.errorMessage = response.data[0];
              }
                  else {
                      $scope.errorMessage = 'Error displaying result user!';
                  }
            });
          }
    }

]);

app.service('StoreService',['$http', function ($http,$q) {

    this.runQuery = function runQuery(statement){
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/runQuery/',
          params: {statement:statement},
          headers: 'Accept:application/json'
        }).then( function(response){
            return reponse.data;
        });
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="StoreController">
    <div class="container">

        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger btn-block"
                style="color: #fff; background-color: #e213a2; border-color: #c3c2c0;"
                name="registration" type="Submit">Logout</button>
        </form>

        <div class="panel-group" style="margin-top: 40px">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span th:utext="${userName}"></span>
                </div>
                    <div>
                <form name="queryForm" method="get" data-ng-submit="runQuery()">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h3 id="queryLabel">Select Query:</h3>
                        <textarea id="query" wrap="soft"
                            placeholder="Please do not enter SELECT with your query, it's added automatically!!" data-ng-model="statement"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit">Run Query</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="results">
                        <h3 id="queryLabel">Result:</h3>
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <th data-ng-repeat="column in cols">{{column}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
                                <td data-ng-repeat="column in cols">{{row[column]}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="admin-message-text text-center" th:utext="${adminMessage}"></p>

                </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The table on the html page, works because I received it from this link
http://jsfiddle.net/v6ruo7mj/1/

But it's not populating the tables with the data received from my backend controller method. I do not have any entities as this is just querying an existing database, so I need not to add any entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue probably is this line here in the service callback within your controller:

```
.then (function (data){
    $scope.rows = response.data;
    // ...
}
```

try with:

```
.then (function (data){
    $scope.rows = data;
    // ...
}
```

You already return the responses data in your service when calling:

```
}).then( function(response){
        return reponse.data;
    });
```

Aside from your question I should mention that your Spring controller seems to be vunerable to SQL injection. It's in general not a good idea to allow the user to access your database directly. Although I don't know how your StoreService on the backend is implemented. But it seems as if an attacker could easily send a HTTP call to your endpoint and drop your database.

Comment: It didn't work for me. But in my repository method. I'm using Jdbctemplate, but what ever the user enter's in the text box it will have select in front of their query. So if they enter DROP SCHEMA, on the backend it'll be SELECT DROP SCHEMA, which will result in an error.

Comment: not if the jdbc connection is configured to allow the execution of multiple statements. Then one could go and issue: `?query=* FROM items; DROP SCHEMA;`
Anyway: Can you check with the browsers web console if the response contains any data?

Comment: So it seems that it is not finding angular files. It says 404 while retrieving the angular documents from the CDN's. But tried to do sql injection, and it did not work. The function i used with Jdbctemplate behind the scenes uses a Preparedstatement, so I think that's the defense for malicious inputs. But  will try to make the files visible and I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the `runQuery` function:

```
app.service('StoreService',['$http', function ($http,$q) {

    this.runQuery = function runQuery(statement){
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/runQuery/',
          params: {statement:statement},
          headers: 'Accept:application/json'
        }).then( function(response){
            ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶;̶
            return response.data
        });
    }
 }]);
```